# How to avoid iterating over Dataloader while resuming training in Huggingface Trainer class?

Tags: pytorch, transformer-model, huggingface-transformers

I'm currently using Huggingface's Trainer class to train Distillbert for a regression problem using a custom loss function. I'm using their checkpoints to resume training due to the ephemeral nature of compute / unexpected errors.

The issue I'm facing is that each time I resume training from a checkpoint as per their Trainer class via the `model_path` in the `Trainer.train()` method, I noticed that the class iterates over the dataloader until it reaches the iteration count as saved in the checkpoint ([see the lines from the Trainer class that match the issue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/33d7506ea10ca92886fd1bb3b5306a1a720c58fe/src/transformers/trainer.py#L500)).

This might usually not be a issue, but due to the nature of my dataloader's collate function and the size of the dataset, iterating for such a duration without any training is pretty expensive and slows down the overall training.

I planned on utilizing a custom sampler class [something along the lines of this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/resume-iterating-dataloader-from-checkpoint-batch-idx/60683) with a parameter to resume the indices from a given location but that too seems quite the hack for the given problem.

What could be an alternative that I could try to save on this wasted compute cycles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like huggingface has provided a solution to this via the use of `ignore_data_skip` argument in the [TrainingArguments](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/trainer.html#transformers.TrainingArguments).

Although you would have to be careful using this flag. It will essentially be as if you're starting a new epoch from step 0. But you'd be moving the optimizer / model state to whatever it was from the resume point.

Comment: That's not a good solution. A better solution that should be implemented is to pass some boolean to the CustomDataset, telling it that we are now in a 'skip' mode, so that the CustomDataset could prevent from doing expensive and unneeded steps in the skipping phase, like for example tokenize words.